# How to iterate over a object that is returned asynchronously and display it in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having trouble with displaying the results of the function call await toxic("a toxic sentence"). The closest i could get was to see this update in the state of the component in react plugin however it did not update the component itself.

```
function ToxicLabels(theObject) {
  return (
  <h2>{theObject.label}  match {theObject.results[0].match}</h2>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      objects: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderThePost()
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    render()
  }

  renderThePost = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await toxic('you suck')
      this.setState({
        object: response,
      })
      // this.state.object.map((object)=>{
      //   console.log(object)
      //   ToxicLabels(object)
      // })
      }catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Hello {"Hola"}</h2>
          {this.state.object.map((object)=> {
            console.log(object)
            ToxicLabels(object)
            })}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

The Structure of data returned. This is how TensorFlow's toxicity model returns data. There is 7 objects in the array. Inside the each object there is a label and an array of results which shows the match(true or false) and the probabilities.

```
{
  "object": [
    {
      "label": "identity_attack",
      "results": [
        "{match: false, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "insult",
      "results": [
        "{match: true, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "obscene",
      "results": [
        "{match: null, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "severe_toxicity",
      "results": [
        "{match: false, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "sexual_explicit",
      "results": [
        "{match: null, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "threat",
      "results": [
        "{match: false, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "toxicity",
      "results": [
        "{match: true, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: not sure tho how to connect that with react.js because the data from the async call is passed into the state of the component however the component does not update

Comment: You could ```map()``` over the data.

Comment: i do map over the data but it does not display component to which i passed the output

Comment: Where is the code for toxic?

Comment: Can you please show the structure of the data returned?

Comment: Can you add `console.log(response)` right after `let response = await toxic('you suck')`? and post what it displays in the console.

Comment: yep i have included them

Comment: You need to return from map --> ```return ToxicLabels( object )```

Comment: I don't think this is it but in your constructor you're naming it ```objects``` and in ```renderThePost``` you're naming it ```object```. I'm surprised it isn't crashing.

Comment: sorry about that i have changed that now to data and regarding return ? Where exactly shall i do it in the return of the class? Shall I map the this.state.object

Comment: ```this.state.object.map( object => { console.log( object ); return ToxicLabel( object )})```

Comment: My first suggestion is remove the componentDidUpdate with it's render method. Second is you have already got the results into state. So no need to use map to iterate the fixed size array. use `{ToxicLabels(this.state.object[0])}`. Tell me if this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works form me, just exclude the toxic function and use your own.

```
import React from "react"

const toxic = () => {
    return {
  "object": [
    {
      "label": "identity_attack",
      "results": [
        "{match: false, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "insult",
      "results": [
        "{match: true, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "obscene",
      "results": [
        "{match: null, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "severe_toxicity",
      "results": [
        "{match: false, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "sexual_explicit",
      "results": [
        "{match: null, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "threat",
      "results": [
        "{match: false, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "toxicity",
      "results": [
        "{match: true, probabilities: Float32Array(2)}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

}

function ToxicLabels(theObject) {
  return (
  <h2>{theObject.label}  match {theObject.results[0].match}</h2>
  )
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      render: false, 
      objects: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderThePost()
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.render()
  }

  renderThePost = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await toxic('you suck')
      console.log( response )
      this.setState({
        objects: response.object,
        render: true
      })
      // this.state.object.map((object)=>{
      //   console.log(object)
      //   ToxicLabels(object)
      // })
      }catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }

  render() {
      if( !this.state.render ) { return <div></div> }
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Hello {"Hola"}</h2>
          {this.state.objects.map((object) => {
            
            return ToxicLabels(object)
            })}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: do i need to change anything if im to add user input from a field. All i need to do is pass the value as a prop to App component right?

Comment: Yeah you'll definitely have to change something but I don't know how you're structuring you code. It sounds like a new question. I'm by no means an expert but I typically have App as my top component and pass props down to children from there.

Comment: ohh i seee I shall do that, im fairly new to react. But the idea is to pass the value in as prop then run the async function right?

Comment: also noob question why do you have render: false in the state

Comment: It's actually not necessary in this case, but if you have state variables that don't get defined until ```componentDidMount``` the app could crash. As to the other question I don't know enough about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense, Im trying to have user input the sentence, then pass that to the tensorflow model, then output the labels and if it matches for each of the label

Comment: Then have your form be a level above where you render Toxic Labels and pass it down as props or set the state after you get the user input.  but honestly this is digressing quite a bit from the original question. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you once again, yh sorry for that its a bit from the question here.

Answer (score 1):

This could work out.

```js
this.setState({
        objects: response.object,
      })
...
{this.state.objects.map((object)=> ToxicLabels(object))}
```

Comment: this on the console gives me object: undefined

Comment: because response has label and an array inside it

Comment: Please share `console.log(response)` result.

Comment: sorry there was error in my code on set state after async was called it was response.object but after i removed it gives me the list

Comment: You should use `objects` state not `object`

Comment: as in the name of the variable?

Comment: Yup, but another issue is in map function.

Comment: shall i just change that to be data instead of object and passing object to ToxicLabels

Comment: Why not? Yes, You can.

Comment: Thank you so much anyway, this actually helped me out. Thank you